# Trouble using mongoose 'Populate'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good Morning,

So I seem to have an issue with populating my fields with Node.js and Mongoose. It is just turning up a blank array:

***Result: (JSON)***

```
[
    {
        "courseassignments": [],
        "_id": "5db56ceb4cc2c92824ae2651",
        "name": "Garibaldi",
        "website": "www.garibaldi.org.uk",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "courseassignments": [],
        "_id": "5db56d074cc2c92824ae2652",
        "name": "Kirk Hallam",
        "website": "www.kirkhallamacademy.co.uk",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Below is the code I am using the call the populate function, plus the models that I am using for each of the data. It is very weird.

***school.js (Model) ***

```
// Require modules within our file:
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    logo: {
        type: Buffer
    },
    courseassignments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, 
        ref: 'CourseAssignment'
    }]
})

// Export the user to use within other files:
const school = mongoose.model('School', schoolSchema)
module.exports = school
```

***courseassignment.js (Model)***

```
// Require modules within our file:
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const courseAssignmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    school: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        required: true,
        ref: 'School'
    },
    course: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Course'
    }
})

// Export the user to use within other files:
const courseAssignment = mongoose.model('CourseAssignment', courseAssignmentSchema)
module.exports = courseAssignment
```

*** Code to fetch data: (within app.js)***

```
router.get('/school', async (req, res) => {

    const schools = await School.find({}).populate({ path: 'courseassignments' })
    res.send(schools)

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the courseassigment ref from the School model, and would take advantage of virtual populate.

So here are the steps:

- school.js (school model - as you see I removed courseassignments  ref, and added options for virtual features)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const schoolSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    logo: {
        type: Buffer
    }
}, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
})

schoolSchema.virtual("courseassignments", {
    ref: "CourseAssignment",
    foreignField: "school",
    localField: "_id"
})

const school = mongoose.model('School', schoolSchema)
module.exports = school
```

At this point when you hit the schools endpoint, your response will be like this.
( I only show one item to be short.)

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
        "name": "school 1",
        "website": "school 1 website",
        "__v": 0,
        "courseassignments": [
            {
                "_id": "5db5a892cfc9951770d50790",
                "school": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
                "course": "5db5a847cfc9951770d5078d",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db5a89ccfc9951770d50791",
                "school": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
                "course": "5db5a851cfc9951770d5078e",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db5a8a1cfc9951770d50792",
                "school": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
                "course": "5db5a858cfc9951770d5078f",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "id": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

And if you also want to access to the Course name (which I think would be good),

- courseassigment.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const courseAssignmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    school: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        required: true,
        ref: 'School'
    },
    course: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Course'
    }
}, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
})

courseAssignmentSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {

    this.populate({
        path: 'course'
    });
    next();
});


// an index may be required like this
//courseAssignmentSchema.index({ school: 1, course: 1 }, { unique: true });

const courseAssignment = mongoose.model('CourseAssignment', courseAssignmentSchema)
module.exports = courseAssignment
```

And with this the result will contain the course related fields like course name.

```
[[
    {
        "_id": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
        "name": "school 1",
        "website": "school 1 website",
        "__v": 0,
        "courseassignments": [
            {
                "_id": "5db5a892cfc9951770d50790",
                "school": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
                "course": {
                    "_id": "5db5a847cfc9951770d5078d",
                    "name": "course 1",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "5db5a892cfc9951770d50790"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db5a89ccfc9951770d50791",
                "school": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
                "course": {
                    "_id": "5db5a851cfc9951770d5078e",
                    "name": "course 2",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "5db5a89ccfc9951770d50791"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5db5a8a1cfc9951770d50792",
                "school": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a",
                "course": {
                    "_id": "5db5a858cfc9951770d5078f",
                    "name": "course 3",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "5db5a8a1cfc9951770d50792"
            }
        ],
        "id": "5db5a809cfc9951770d5078a"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

Docs:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals