# MongoDB / Mongoose one-to-many relationship

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Working on a database structure for a new project, and trying to figure out how exactly one-to-many relationships in MongoDB / mongoose work.

So considering a following simple structure :

I have a project table/schema with multiple images linked to it:

```
const ProjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, // Just the id,
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true,  maxLength: 60 },
    description: { type: String, required: false }, 
    images: [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image'
    }]
});
```

And then an image table/schema:

```
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, // Just the id,
    url: { type: String, unique: true, required: true }
    project: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project'
    }        
});
```

I want one-to-many between images and projects, so I save an image with a project id:

```
const image = new Image(
        {
                project: project._id,
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                url: 'https://someurl',
        });        
        await image.save();
```

If I then find this image, and populate the project field - it contains all the project's info nicely, BUT if I find this project, it doesn't have anything in the images array (referencing Image):

```
images: [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image'
    }]
```

I thought that with ref you're creating the foreign key reference between Project and Image and then both Image should have the linked Project and Project should see the linked image in the array.
Is that not the case or am I missing something here ?

Comment: How do you query project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to populate images from project with no problem.

Let's say you have this project document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e592a438b93764a40a81a96"),
    "images" : [
        ObjectId("5e592aba8b93764a40a81a98"),
        ObjectId("5e592ac78b93764a40a81a99")
    ],
    "name" : "Project 1",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And these image documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e592ac78b93764a40a81a99"),
    "url" : "Url 2",
    "project" : ObjectId("5e592a438b93764a40a81a96"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e592aba8b93764a40a81a98"),
    "url" : "Url 1",
    "project" : ObjectId("5e592a438b93764a40a81a96"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

We can use the following code to populate images:

```js
router.get("/projects/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Project.findById(req.params.id).populate("images");
  res.send(result);
});
```

This will give a result like this:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "_id": "5e592aba8b93764a40a81a98",
            "url": "Url 1",
            "project": "5e592a438b93764a40a81a96",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e592ac78b93764a40a81a99",
            "url": "Url 2",
            "project": "5e592a438b93764a40a81a96",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5e592a438b93764a40a81a96",
    "name": "Project 1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

So for your case, check if your project document really contains images array with the Object ids for image documents, and you populate correctly.

Also you don't need to add _id fields to the schema, mongodb will itself generate _id automatically.

project

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProjectSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, maxLength: 60 },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  images: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Image"
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", ProjectSchema);
```

image

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
  url: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  project: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Project"
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Image", ImageSchema);
```

Comment: thanks ! but what I mean is this - having this schema structure, if I add a new image having reference to the project , say : "project" : ObjectId("5e592a438b93764a40a81a96"), ,should the project of that id have this image AUTOMATICALLY appearing in the images array ? When I query project like  `const foundProject = await Project
            .find({ name: project.name })
            .populate('category status creator images')  `  it shows empty images array []

Comment: @RRob you need to populate as I showed in the answer. Also when you create a new image, you should add that image id to the project’s images array. I already showed sample documents.

Comment: got it, so for example when I'm creating new image linked to a project, I have to always explicitly add it to the image array in the Project, correct ?

Comment: @RRob yes it is true.

Comment: @RRob there is also another way of setting schemas with parent referencing where we don’t keep images in the project, but keep only the project reference in the image. That way when we create an image, we dont need to put the image id to the project, but in order to reference images from project, we need to setup populate virtual on the project schema. If you are interested this solution, I can add this info to my answer tomorrow.

Comment: sounds really interesting, please do if you find a moment tomorrow <3

Comment: @RRob I have some virtual populate samples in these answers. Can you check them please? [sample1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59144537/11717458),  [sample2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580586/11717458)